# Error: spawn terraform ENOENT during Azure Pipeline running Terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, yaml, azure-pipelines

Error: spawn terraform ENOENT during Azure Pipeline Terraform

How to solve this error and how to specify the path in azure devops to working directory while running yaml script for terraform

Answer (score 1):

The "ENOENT" error typically occurs when the system cannot find the specified file or command. To solve this error, you need to ensure that the Terraform executable is installed on the agent machine where the pipeline is running. You can do this by adding a task to install Terraform before running the pipeline.
To specify the working directory for the Terraform task in Azure DevOps, you can use the "workingDirectory" parameter in the task definition. For example, if your Terraform files are located in a subdirectory called "terraform", you can specify the working directory like this:

```
- task: TerraformCLI@0
  inputs:
    command: 'apply'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform'
```

This will ensure that the Terraform command is executed in the correct directory. Make sure to adjust the path to match the location of your Terraform files.